# Python - level order traversal using dict vs queue

Tags: python, time-complexity, tree-traversal, breadth-first-search

My understanding of Algo & DS is a bit novice. And I'm not sure if this is a duplicate or related question or if completely trivial. Wherever I see level order traversal or BFS being mentioned I see a **queue** used. I'm not able to understand the intricacies of that, in terms of space and more importantly **time complexity**, **against** my implementation using **dictionary**.

```
def getLevelElements(tree, level=0, cont={}):
    """Get mapping of level and elements in a level
    :param tree: Input tree, ex.
        1
            2
                4
                5
                    8
                    9
            3
                6
                7
                    10
                    None
    :return: {0: [1], 1: [2, 3], 2: [4, 5, 6, 7], 3: [8, 9, 10]}
    """
    if tree is not None:
        cont.setdefault(level, []).append(tree.root)
    if tree.leftChild is not None:
        getLevelElements(tree.leftChild, level + 1, cont)
    if tree.rightChild is not None:
        getLevelElements(tree.rightChild, level + 1, cont)
    return cont


def levelOrderTraversalOut(tree):
    levelElementsMap = getLevelElements(tree)
    out = []
    for elements in levelElementsMap.values():
        out += elements
    return out
```

My requirement is to get elements of tree in a list using level order traversal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need a BFS-order of elements of the tree.
I would suggest smth like this:

```
def bfs(tree):
    out = []
    elements = [tree.root]
    while elements:
        elem = elements.pop(0)
        out.append(elem)
        if elem.leftChild:
            elements.append(elem.leftChild)
        if elem.rightChild:
            elements.append(elem.rightChild)
    return out
```

Comment: True. Though would you also help me understand complexities of your solution against my solution - both time and space?

Comment: Yes. In both solutions each element of the tree is traversed only once, so they have linear time complexity. The same thing with space complexity in both solutions.